# How to set ActionView without loosing ActionProvider

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, android-menu

I'm trying to make a menu item `"Refresh"` animated.

Long story short, I execute: `setActionView(ImageView)` - which sets new animated image view instead of default icon. But clicking on the menu item after first refresh will not do anything...

If I try to execute: `setActionProvider(ActionProvider)` to set the old default action manually - then the new animated image view is not displayed, because it overrides `setActionView(ImageView)`...

I can not use `setActionView(null)` after refresh because it makes all other menu items "blink" and that drives me crazy.

How do I get both: new `ImageView` and default `ActionProvider` for a menu item?

Thx for reading so far! :-)